# Only a-z and A-Z character is allowed between ::

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make regular express which will allow only a-z and A-Z character between :: .

Like

> My :head: is on :fire:

I have find something like this

```
 /:.+?:/g
```

Which allow all character between `::`

How to Allow only character a-z and A-Z ?

Comment: The question mark after plus symbol has no sense, it is the same as asterisk (.+? = .*). In any case, any character will include also ":", so you could specify "all characters but ":" with /:[^:]*:/g (but that will include more characters that from a-z and A-Z (that would be /:[a-zA-Z]*:/g)

Comment: [Which](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html) [language](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) [are](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) [you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions) [using](http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/:[a-zA-Z]*:/g` regex.

Have a look at the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cW8fW1/1).

Example code:

```
var re = /:[a-zA-Z]*:/g; 
var str = ':mystring:';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put A-Z, a-z inside a character class and place it between the two colons.

```
:[A-Za-z]+:
```

`+` after the character class will repeat the previous token one or more times. So this `[A-Za-z]+` would match one or more alphabets.

In javascript, you need to use match function like

```
> var str = 'My :head: is on :fire:'
undefined
> str.match(/:[A-Za-z]+:/g)
[ ':head:', ':fire:' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:[a-z]+:
```

Try this with `i` modifier.